# How to you be able to show the map in the simulator using OSMdroid?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, osmdroid

Im working on a navigation project using osmdroid. 
I'm using Android studio for developing that app

This is my Activity class

```
package com.example.dummmmy.dummmmmy;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private MapController mapController;
    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(15);
        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(51496994, -134733);
        mapController.setCenter(point2);
    }

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and this is my activity.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my mainfest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dummmmy.dummmmmy" >


    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and when am trying to run the app on the simulator I have an empty grey grid with no map, and errors.

This is the error

> 09-15 22:27:27.090      332-349/com.example.dummmmy.dummmmmy W/org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileDownloader﹕ Problem downloading MapTile: /15/16369/10895 HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
>   09-15 22:27:27.161      332-346/com.example.dummmmy.dummmmmy W/org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileDownloader﹕ Problem downloading MapTile: /15/16384/16384 HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
>   09-15 22:27:27.399      332-349/com.example.dummmmy.dummmmmy D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 873 objects / 402472 bytes in 57ms
>   09-15 22:27:27.610      332-349/com.example.dummmmy.dummmmmy W/org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileDownloader﹕ Problem downloading MapTile: /15/16383/16383 HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Comment: Which version of osmdroid?

Comment: OSMdroid 3.0.8 how would that affect my app ?

Comment: Now, i got the mapp showing but whenever I try to access my location using MyLocationOverlay, it shows nothing at all not even the grey grid.

Comment: osmdroid 3.0.8 cannot work anymore with the default tile source (osmdroid issue #515). You must use at least osmdroid 4.1. I assume this is what you did? And MyLocationOverlay is another issue?

Comment: I'm not able to display my location in the map. and I'm using MAPQUESTOSM as a source tiles

Comment: So your initial issue is solved (effectively, MAPQUESTOSM tiles are still working under 3.0.8). And you have now a new distinct issue => open a new one, and provide relevant code. But, first of all, you should upgrade to the latest osmdroid version.